# What is the use of MongoDB in GrayLog2?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, graylog2

GrayLog2 requires both ElasticSearch and MongoDB, while Logstash uses only ElasticSearch for persisting and searching the logs. `what does mongo provide in graylog2?`

Comment: This was the first Google search result for `graylog2 mongodb`: http://alexey-palazhchenko.tumblr.com/post/5070526903/graylog2-and-its-mongodb-usage

Comment: The link you shared does not use Elastic Search at all, the config that I'm looking at uses Elastic Search for persistent storage.

Comment: What is your question then? `"What does mongo provide in graylog2?"` That blog post addressed the question as stated.

Comment: You cannot use ES as persistance layer, ES is a search engine, Mongo a database, they do what they are made for!

Comment: Why the choice of mongo over mysql? Like was there a technical reason, or a performance reason, or perhaps it was just a preference? I've always been curios.

Comment: @Canadian_Republican Mongo and MySQL are both DBMSes but quite different. Mongo is great when you have a lot of data and want to do on the fly computations. Perf is another factor, no table locks, no transactions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Graylog2 uses mongodb for the web interface entities. Streams, alerts, users, settings, cached stream counts etc. Pretty much everything you see and edit in the web interface except for the logs themselves.